# javax.mail no longer working with java 11 and tomcat 8.5

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-mail, java-11

I am using `java 11.0.4 2019-07-16 LTS` on `Ubunutu 18` and `Apache Tomcat 8.5`.

I created a class for sending emails that imports

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
```

Now, when I used `java 8`I did not have any problems with sending my emails. However, now it does not work instead I am getting a 500 error.

And having a look at my `localhost.2019-08-20.log` I can find the following stacktrace:

```
20-Aug-2019 17:13:14.961 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-96] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [mlc.servlets.DispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataHandler
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1360)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1182)
        at mlc.Mailer.sendEMail(Mailer.java:35)
        ...and so on...
```

Doing some research I think the problem is that the module `java.activation` is not loaded.

However, I did not find any solution on the internet. I only found that `java.activation` has been removed from java 11. So, I guess I need something else.

So, my questions: What do I have to do that my webapp can - again - send emails using Tomcat 8.5?

Thanks

Comment: I see you marked this as 'answered'.. Do you mind sharing how you got this to work?  Mainly, how did you get both javax.mail and the updated javax.activation on the classpath and how did you get your app to use the 1.2.1 activation classes and not the 1.1 classes.  I'm using Gradle, and in spite of me 'implementing' both successfully, my app classes uses the 1.1 version when I try to instantiate the javax.activation.DataHandler.java in my mail class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include the [latest version](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.1/jar) of javax.activation in your program.

Comment: But how do you force those classes to get used?  I put ```implementation 'com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1'``` right next to ```implementation 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.2'``` in my build.gradle file, but at runtime my class keeps using the old activation-1.1.jar...

Comment: @Atom999  Do you have something else that depends on the old version?

Comment: @BillShannonYes, javax.mail depends on 1.1

Comment: @Atom999It should work with 1.1 or newer.  You have to make sure you include the newer version if you're using JDK 11.  Between Maven and JDK modules, this is all way too complicated.

Comment: @BillShannon Yea I guess my issued lied elsewhere.  For Java8 we were just dropping a byte[] into the javax.activation.DataHandler constructor and it worked for years.  With Java11, for reasons I'm not sure of yet, now we have to make a ByteArrayDataSource object first and use that in the DataHandler constructor.  And that is with using the older mail 1.5.2 with the activation 1.1 dependency.  (in case some poor soul stumbles across this in the future) Thanks for the comments though!!